# how to disable angular2-date-picker?

Tags: angular

I am using `[disabled]="true"` for disable datepicker,

**app.component.html**:

```
<div>
  <angular2-date-picker [(ngModel)]="date" [settings]="settings" [disabled]="true"></angular2-date-picker>
</div
```

**app.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({    
  selector: 'app-root',  
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',  
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'] 
})

export class AppComponent {
  date: Date = new Date(); 
  settings = {
    bigBanner: false,
    timePicker: false,    
    format: 'dd-MM-yyyy',    
    defaultOpen: false,    
    disabled: true    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try pointer-events

> The pointer-events CSS property sets under what circumstances (if any)
>   a particular graphic element can become the target of mouse events

```
  <angular2-date-picker [(ngModel)]="date" [settings]="settings" 
  [ngStyle]="{'pointer-events': true ? 'none' : 'auto' }" >
  </angular2-date-picker>
```